# Как найти ноду, если нет уникального селектора

Tags: javascript, html, rest, frontend, dom

Всем доброго времени суток! Возникла проблема. Делаю запрос на сервер, получаю данные. Массив объектов вида {name: , gender: , id: , ...}. По получению данных нужно отрендерить 10 карточек на странице. Есть структура карточки. Полученные данные засовываю в массив, потом методом .reduce возвращаю структуру для всех десяти карточек и с помощью .insertAdjacentHTML добавляю на страницу. Получается вот такая структура

```html
<div class="requests__cards-card ">
    <div class="requests__cards-imgBlock">
        <img alt="#">
    </div>
    <div class="requests__cards-descr">
        <div class="requests__bearName"></div> 
        <div class="requests__bearTypeNGender"></div>
        <div class="requests__bearTypeNGender"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="requests__cards-btns">
        <button class="btn--accept"></button>
        <button class="btn--reject"></button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="requests__cards-card ">
    <div class="requests__cards-imgBlock">
        <img alt="#">
    </div>
    <div class="requests__cards-descr">
        <div class="requests__bearName"></div> 
        <div class="requests__bearTypeNGender"></div>
        <div class="requests__bearTypeNGender"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="requests__cards-btns">
        <button class="btn--accept"></button>
        <button class="btn--reject"></button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="requests__cards-card ">
    <div class="requests__cards-imgBlock">
        <img alt="#">
    </div>
    <div class="requests__cards-descr">
        <div class="requests__bearName"></div> 
        <div class="requests__bearTypeNGender"></div>
        <div class="requests__bearTypeNGender"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="requests__cards-btns">
        <button class="btn--accept"></button>
        <button class="btn--reject"></button>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

Дальше на каждую карточку нужно навесить обработчик событий. Кликая на карточку должна появляться большая карточка с доп информацией, которая берется из массива. Так вот проблема заключается в том что уникального селектора на карточках нет, классы все одинаковые. Как находить нужную ноду? До возникновения этой проблемы давал каждой карточке id, после чего навешивал обработчик

```js
array.forEach(item => {
  const card = document.getElementById(item.id)
  card.addEventListener('click', () => renderBigCard)
})
```

Однако кое-кто сказал мне, что "плодить" айдишники - это плохой тон) Поэтому я их убрал, но полностью отсутствуют в голове идеи, как бы решить эту проблему не используя уникальных селекторов. Может есть у кого какие идеи?
Скриншот функции, собирающих карточку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD
Пришла в голову идея записывать ноду в массив. Т.е. я нахожу все ноды своих карточек, после чего для каждого элемента массива добавляю параметр item.node и уже на него вешаю обработчик события. Пример кода ниже

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.requests__cards-card')
    bearsArr.forEach(item => {
        item.node = nodes[item.id-1]
        item.node.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            renderBigCard(item)
        })
    })
```

Comment: `data-id="?"` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes И соответственно собирать массив по селектору — `[data-id]`

Comment: Почему атрибут `id` это плохой тон? Может я что упустил?

Comment: @SwaD Было сказано, что **плодить** их плохой тон, а не весь атрибут плохой тон.

Comment: Та вот не объяснил) Сказал что если у меня будет 1000 карточек, то у меня айдишники расплодятся как кролики и мол это плохо. Сказал, что для таких случаев есть замыкания. Но ничего не приходит в голову, как сделать это через замыкания, я немного того... новичок еще) Человек, который курирует по проекту, так сказать, мидл+ фронт.

Comment: Покажите фунцию, которая собирает и рендерит ваши карточки

Comment: @SwaD добавил скриншот в тело вопроса. В комментариях нельзя скриншоты.

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть кое какая идея. Необходимо помещать карточки в некий контейнер назовём его wrapper. И к этому контейнеру подключим обработчик событий. И при  помощи делигирования обрабатываем события клик только на нужном нам элементе.

```js
const wr = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wr.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('requests__cards-card')){
    if (e.target.style.backgroundColor === 'green' || e.target.style.backgroundColor === '') {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    } else {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
    console.log(e.target.children[0].textContent);
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.requests__cards-card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <div class="requests__cards-card ">
    <p>Карточка 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="requests__cards-card ">
    <p>Карточка 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="requests__cards-card ">
    <p>Карточка 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема не уходит все равно) Как обработчик будет понимать, что произошел клик именно на вторую карточку, к примеру? Есть массив объектов [{name: 'Я карточка 1', text: 'один'}, {name: 'Я карточка 2', text: 'два'}{name: 'Я карточка 3'}, text: 'три']. По этому массиву вы рендерите карточку, а name вставляете в <p> в вашем примере. И вот нужно для каждой карточки сделать обработчик событий, который будет выводить в консоль text именно той карточки, на которую кликнул. Т.е. карточки уникальные. В вашем же примере изначально все карточки зеленые и не имеют уникальности.

Comment: @GorkaChannel кажется я вам уже предложил правильное решение с атрибутом [data]. С ним-то что не так? Единственное в чём прав автор выше, так это то, что не стоит безо всякого смысла развешивать Listener-ы на каждую карточку, а можно повесить один на весь блок, но вы хотя бы с первой частью предложенного мной решения справьтесь. Куда уж проще? `<div class="requests__cards-card" data-id="2">`

Comment: @GorkaChannel Судя по Вашему комментарию Вы не поняли принцип. Каждая выведенная мной карточка уникальная и не важно что она зеленая важно то что обработчик событий понимает на какой карточке произошло событие. Для того чтобы Вы поняли я выведу в консоль текст карточки по которой произойдет клик.